# STM32F107VC Running a FreeRTOS with TCP

Tags: sockets, stm32, freertos, lwip, visualgdb

I need to develop an application on my eval board: STM3210-c (chip: stm32f107vc) which creates threads.
Each thread creates a TCP client and is able to connect to a different slave.

I thought about using FreeRTOS & lwip (and preferably working with the socket functionality of the lwip).

But I want to use sockets, I don't want to have to manage the packets.
I've tried to compile the LwIP with support for sockets but I can't get it to compile.

The flags I've set in lwipopts.h are:

`#define LWIP_TIMEVAL_PRIVATE                            0
 #define LWIP_NETCONN                                     1
 #define LWIP_SOCKET                                      1`

When I try to compile I get an error that lwip/netbuf.h does not exist.

1. Is there an example of code how to use freertos & lwip sockets?
2. Is there a different library which I need to consider?

   - I am using VisualGDB.

Any offers or code sample would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not lwIP, but the following may offer an alternative that is tightly integrated with FreeRTOS  http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP-IP_FAT_Examples_ST_STM32F407.html

Comment: Is there an example for stm32f107? This example is for stm32f407.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to generate your project with stm32cube? Just add LwIP there and enable sockets API. Everything works perfectly.

And you can download examples for stm32 from  [STM32Cube Embedded Software](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software.html). There are examples with sockets API.